# How do I replace "fancy" unicode chars with their ascii equivalends?

Tags: files, unicode

Is there a tool to replace fancy utf chars like `U+2018` (LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK), `U+2019` (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) with normal quote chars: `'`, etc. like lodash deburr command does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iconv`

```
NAME
       iconv - Convert encoding of given files from one encoding to another

SYNOPSIS
       iconv -f encoding [-t encoding] [inputfile]...
```

e.g.

```
$ echo "some ‘fancy’ chars" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit
some 'fancy' chars
```